# State trajectory estimation - least square

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, least-squares

I have a question regarding least square estimation and state trajectory.

I have the problem:

[image]

but I don't understand how I can rewrite the subject to? I believe that you can set the minimization to the form:
$$||y  - Cx||_{2}^{2}$$

and then just expand that to:

$$y^{T}y - 2y^{T}Cx + x^{T}C^{T}Cx$$

is that correct?

But I don't know what to do with the subject to, to finally reach the x(0) expression.

Grateful for all the help I can get.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by $\|y - Cx\|^2$? We know what $x_i$ is, but what exactly is $x$ here?

Comment: I thought that you can summarize over all x_i so in the end we end up with y-Cx, but maybe I am wrong?

Comment: What does "summarizing over all $x_i$" mean?

Comment: Also, this isn't your fault, but your problem is inconsistent about whether there is a vector $x_0$ or the first vector is $x_1$.

Comment: I think my problem is that I don't know how to handle the summation in this, I am not sure how to simplify that part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is that we want to reframe this problem as an **unconstrained** least squares optimization. Currently, the problem is framed as a search for $m$ vectors $x_1,\dots,x_m$ satisfying the **constraint** that $x_{i+1} = Ax_i$ for $i = 1,\dots,m$. To that end, we can note that as soon as we decide on an initial state $x_1$, the remainder of the $x_i$ are completely determined, and there are no limitations on our choice of $x_1$. In particular, for **any** $x_1$, we have
$$
x_2 = Ax_1, \quad x_3 = Ax_2 = A^2x_1, \quad x_4 = Ax_3 = A^3 x_1, \dots,
$$
and so forth, which is to say that $x_{i} = A^{i-1}x_1$. Thus, we can rewrite the problem as the following unconstrained minimization:
$$
\min_{x_1} \frac 12 \sum_{i=1}^m \|Cx_i - y_i\|^2 = \min_{x_1} \frac 12 \sum_{i=1}^m \|CA^{i-1}x_1 - y_i\|^2 = 
\frac 12 \min_{x_1}  \sum_{i=1}^m \|CA^{i-1}x_1 - y_i\|^2.
$$
In order to frame this in terms of traditional least squares, it is helpful to represent this minimization in the form $\min_{x_1} \sum_i \|CA^{i-1}x_1 - y_i\|^2$ in the form $\min_{x_1} \|Mx - b\|^2$ for some matrix $M$ and vector $b$. We can do this nicely with the help of block-matrix operations. We have
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^m \|CA^{i-1}x_1 - y_i\|^2 &= \left\|\pmatrix{Cx_1\\ CAx_1 \\ \vdots \\ CA^{m-1}x_1}  - 
\pmatrix{y_1\\ y_2\\ \vdots \\ y_m}\right\|
= 
\left\|
\pmatrix{C\\CA\\ \vdots \\ CA^{m-1}} x_1 - \pmatrix{y_1\\ y_2\\ \vdots \\ y_m}
\right\|,
\end{align}
so that our optimization is in the form $\min_{x_1} \|Mx_1 - b\|^2$ with
$$
M = \pmatrix{C\\CA\\ \vdots \\ CA^{m-1}}, \quad b = \pmatrix{y_1\\ y_2\\ \vdots \\ y_m}.
$$
Perhaps you can take it from there.

Comment: Okay I understand that part, thank you! But I think I am still having problem what the subject to should be?

Comment: Okay I saw now that you wrote unconstrained, my bad!

Comment: Thank you for the help! I understand and solved it now. Appreciate it.

Comment: @JK Glad to hear it. I'd appreciate if you could "accept" this answer then by clicking the check mark ($\checkmark$) on the upper-left corner of my post.